# how to do a join query to get wanted values

Tags: postgresql

I have table **article** that contains this values

| Date | MyID | Texte |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 06/05/2019 | AC19011 | value 1 |
| 23/12/2016 | P811610-12 | value 2 |
| 29/11/2017 | P8116-150 | value 3 |

my second table **file** that contains this values

| MyID | link |
| --- | --- |
| AC19011 | http:/link1.com |

I would like to do a query to get this result

| Date | MyID | Texte | link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06/05/2019 | AC19011 | value 1 | http:/link1.com |
| 23/12/2016 | P811610-12 | value 2 |  |
| 29/11/2017 | P8116-150 | value 3 |  |

i have done an inner join query it get me only one line .

how could i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN. E.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM article a
LEFT OUTER JOIN file f ON f.MyID = a.MyID
```